# Interceptor class visibility in Byte Buddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Byte Buddy seems to only appreciate public classes as interceptor implementations even if I provide the actual instance; frequently I find myself wanting to do something like this:

```
import static MethodDelegation.to;

new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class).method(any()).intercept(to(new Object() {
  @RuntimeType
  public Object intercept(@Origin Method m, @AllArguments Object[] a) {
    return null;
  }
});
```

Which however results in an exception as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: class net.bytebuddy.renamed.java.lang.Object$ByteBuddy$pUmdGhyP cannot access class us.levk.guice.vs.Scopes$1Builder$1
```

Is there any reason behind visibility enforcement?

EDIT: I'm still having trouble with it though; I'm getting a different exception, this is my code:

```
package us.levk.guice.vs;

import static net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation.to;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.any;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.AllArguments;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Origin;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;

public class Bar {

  Function<Supplier<?>, Class<?>> wrapper () {
    return s -> {
      return new ByteBuddy ().subclass (Object.class)
                             .name (Bar.class.getPackage ().getName () + ".Foo")
                             .method (any ())
                             .intercept (to (new Object () {
                               @RuntimeType
                               public Object intercept (@Origin Method method,
                                                        @AllArguments Object[] args) {
                                 System.out.println (method);
                                 return null;
                               }
                             }))
                             .make ()
                             .load (getClass ().getClassLoader (),
                                    ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
                             .getLoaded ();
    };
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    new Bar ().wrapper ().apply ( () -> new Integer (1)).newInstance ().toString ();
  }
}
```

And the exception is now:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class us.levk.guice.vs.Bar$1 from class us.levk.guice.vs.Foo
```

EDIT2:

It works fine if I change the classloading strategy to INJECTION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, Byte Buddy informs you about a visibility constraint that would cause an `IllegalAccessException` at runtime.

Eventhough you declare your method `public`, the anonymous class is automatically defined to be package private by *javac*. Therefore, the method is not visible to the generated class since `net.bytebuddy.renamed.java.lang.Object` is not equal to `us.levk.guice.vs.Scopes`.

If you did:

```
new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class).name("us.levk.guice.vs.Foo")
               .method(any()).intercept(to(new Object() {
  @RuntimeType
  public Object intercept(@Origin Method m, @AllArguments Object[] a) {
    return null;
  }
}));
```

everything would work. Alternatively, you can define - for example - a public interface such as:

```
public interface Foo {
  @RuntimeType
  Object intercept(@Origin Method m, @AllArguments Object[] a);
}

new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class).name("us.levk.guice.vs.Foo")
               .method(any()).intercept(to(new Foo() {
  @RuntimeType
  public Object intercept(@Origin Method m, @AllArguments Object[] a) {
    return null;
  }
}, Foo.class));
```